# In Qt creator running system command

Tags: c++, qt, system

I am trying to write a widget in qt in order to use some commands with gui .When I write

```
system("pwd");
```

I can get the output but when I try to get some other command I couldn't get the the output For example I wrote

```
system("compgen -c");
```

to list all the commands I got the error `sh: 1: compgen: not found`
Can qt run all the commands by using system or not? how can ı run the 
`system("compgen -c");` 
please help me

Comment: Did you try using the full absolute path to your program? Your terminal might have another $PATH set. Also: `pwd` is a shell build-in command in some shells: Compare `bash -c "which pwd"`, `dash -c "which pwd"`, `zsh -c "which pwd"`. Thus `date` might be a better test example.

Comment: I tried .output is the same which is /bin/pwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compgen` is bash builtin command. It means that there is no binary file named `compgen` in your system and Qt cannot execute it directly. It's only available in bash. You should pass this command to bash:

```
system("bash -c 'compgen -c'");
```

Comment: It works thanks and one more thing I installed ec2 cli tools and I want to run them for example "ec2-describe-regions" but  command is not running by using this notation any suggestion please

Comment: Where are the tools installed? What is the output of `which ec2-describe-regions`

Comment: I installed them in /usr/local/ec2/ec2-api-tools-1.7.2.3/bin
and when i try to write echo $PATH in terminal I can see that path above in the output but in qt when I write system("echo $PATH"); I could not see the path above it is strange . How can ı enable qt to see that path also?